Which robot should I use in Gazebo Sim with ROS 2 Rolling and Ubuntu 24.04 for 3D navigation?
I want to experiment with several 3D navigation methods in Gazebo, but I’ve noticed that in TurtleBot 3, the RGB-D camera is optional, and code modifications are required to enable that sensor and retrieve point clouds. Which robot would you recommend for ROS 2 Rolling, Gazebo Sim, and Ubuntu 24.04? I see there are many options—Husky, Jackal, Fetch Robot—but I’m unsure which is the best for my scenario. Thank you!

I finally chose to work with the TurtleBot 4 robot because it meets all the requirements I was looking for.
